# install fontawesome fonts in R

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R  am am trying to import downloaded fontawesome font by using this command:-

```
extrafont::font_import (path="C:\\Users\\qrs19x\\Downloads", pattern = "awesome", prompt = FALSE)
```

But get the following error message-

```
Scanning ttf files in C:\Users\qrs19x\Downloads ...
Extracting .afm files from .ttf files...
Error in data.frame(fontfile = ttfiles, FontName = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

Can anyone advise me if I am doing something incorrectly

Thanks